# Measure : $μ^{*}(G\bigtriangleup A)=0$.

Tags: measure-theory

I'm new to measure theory,so i need some help.

$G\bigtriangleup A=(A\setminus G)\cup (G\setminus A)$.

So, let $A, G\subset \Bbb R$ with $μ^{*}(G\bigtriangleup A)=0$.
 What can we say for $μ^{*}(A)$ and $μ^{*}(G)$?(i think that they will be equal).

I know that $G\bigtriangleup A$ is measurable because $μ^{*}(G\bigtriangleup A)=0$. Can i achieve with the $\sigma-$ algebra's properties something? Any other thoughts?

Comment: Note that $\mu(A\bigtriangleup G)=\int|1_A-1_G|$ then $1_A=1_G$ $\mu-a.e.$

Comment: @O.B.D.A., thanks for answering but unfortunately i cannot understand your idea.I don't want to use integration ideas.

Comment: Do you know that if f is positive then $\int f d\mu=0\Leftrightarrow f=0$ $\mu-a.e.$

Comment: @user113576 May be this could help :  $\mu(A \cup B) \le \mu(A) + \mu(B)$

Comment: @O.B.D.A. That's too much for people like us who just started measure theory .

Comment: Can you please write more concretely, what the problem is ?

Comment: Does $\mu^*$ stand for outer measure? Because for Lebesgue measure it is more difficult. For outer measure you think right.

Comment: @sas, yes it's the outer measure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose it should be like this.

$\mu^*(A\setminus G)\leq μ^{*}(G\bigtriangleup A)=0$ so $\mu^*(A\setminus G)=\mu^*(G\setminus A)=0$. 
$\mu^*(A\cup G)=\mu^*(A\cup (G\setminus A))\leq \mu^*A +\mu^*(G\setminus A)=\mu^*A$
and $\mu^*A\leq \mu^*(A\cup G)$
so $\mu^*A= \mu^*(A\cup G)$
The same for $G$ and finally $\mu^*A=\mu^*G$.

But for Lebesgue measure...

Let $M$ be the set with a property: for every Lebesgue measurable $E:\mu_*(M\cap E)=0,\,\mu^*(M\cap E)=\mu^*E=\mu E$ where $\mu_*$ stands for inner measure and $M$ is not Lebesgue measurable. 
Let then $A=[0,1], G=M\cap A$.
So, you have $μ^{*}(G\bigtriangleup A)=0$ which implies $μ(G\bigtriangleup A)=0$.
And finally, $μ(G\bigtriangleup A)=0, \, \mu A=1$ and $G$ is not Lebesgue measurable.